# Migration Vuetify 2 to Vuetify 3 - Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lgAndUp') App.vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I'm in the process of migrating from Vuetify2 to Vuetify3. After going through the documentation and launching the application I am running into an error found in the App.vue file: 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lgAndUp')'. It appears that the vuetify.breakpoint property is not being read which seems to indicate that vuetify may not be loading properly. I've been going back through the main.js and App.vue files and bouncing the code against the documentation to see what I might be missing. I have also recently migrated from Vue2 to Vue3. See file code below:

`
main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
//import Vuetify from 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.js';
//import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
import 'vuetify/styles';
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify';
import * as components from 'vuetify/components';
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives';

import axios from 'axios';
import App from '@/App.vue';
import router from '@/router';
import store from '@/store';
...
...
const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
});

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
window.axios.defaults.baseURL = siteURL;

createApp(App).use(vuetify).use(router).use(store).mount('#app');`
```

`
App.vue

```
...
...
<!--Top Toolbar-->
    <v-app-bar
      v-if="usersStore.authUser"
      :clipped-left="$vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp"
      color="primary"
      dark
      flat
      app
      fixed
    >
...
...
import vuetify from "vuetify";
```

`

I have tried printing the vuetify component to the console to test if it is loading properly and it returned 'undefined' which suggests that it is not loaded or perhaps not referenced properly.

Comment: The error means that it was initialized correctly, it's specifically $vuetify.breakpoint that doesn't exist. Such things are covered by migration guide in properly maintained libs. This isn't an exclusion, https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/upgrade-guide/#layout

Comment: Geeeze, I knew it would be something small. I overlooked updating the 'breakpoint' property to change it to 'display'. This fixed the error. Thankyou.